# Getting instance of Extension Delegate in WatchKit InterfaceController

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to get the instance of ExtensionDelegate in InterfaceController in Apple Watch application but can't seem to find a way. I have created a method in Extension Delegate that I need to call and for that I would need a shared instance of Extension Delegate. Is there a way to do so?

Like for iOS App, we call it like:

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] methodName];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the ExtensionDelegate with the line below. Be sure to import WatchKit.

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>

ExtensionDelegate* myDelegate = (ExtensionDelegate*)[[WKExtension sharedExtension] delegate];
[myDelegate methodName];
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get the same

ExtensionDelegate* myDelegate = (ExtensionDelegate*)[[WKExtension sharedExtension] delegate];